# an evil humour in his thigh

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Henry says, ‘The Emperor, two or three years back when he was in
>   Germany, did he not have **an evil humour in his thigh**? They say the
>   weather didn't suit him. But then his dominions offer a change of
>   climate. Whereas from one part of my kingdom to the next there is no
>   change to be found.’
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

Does "**an evil humour**" mean some kind of rheumatism or pain in his thigh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You nailed it!

The system of Ayurveda that I have learned in my professional career believes that there are three *[doshas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosha)* that form the body. Likewise, [four bodily humors were part of Shakespearean cosmology](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/exhibition/shakespeare/fourhumors.html), inherited from the ancient Greek philosophers Aristotle, Hippocrates, and Galen.

The word 'evil' serves here as 'bad/ill' or maybe paining.

The [OALD entry](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/humour_1) supports the term humor in this sentence:

> *one of the four liquids that were thought in the past to be in a person’s body and to **influence health** and character*

Certainly, it's the pain in his thighs the author is talking about. I wouldn't have guessed it if there was no following sentences supporting it here!

Very good question +1

Comment: I would note that that definition of *humor* is somewhat archaic and not commonly used today.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, an "evil humour" means "an uncomfortable illness or pain." The word "evil" here is used as indicated in Merriam-Webster, definition 2 (a):  *causing discomfort or repulsion*. *Humour* references the ancient theory of the humors: blood, phlegm, (yellow) bile and black bile, imbalances in which were believed to be behind virtually all illnesses. A note: from this we get the words *sanguine* (cheerful), *choleric* or *bilious* (ill-tempered), *phlegmatic* (calm), and *melancholic* (sad).